# Rails refactoring a method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

im a new developer and i need some help to refactor this code

So, I have a Rails App with a controller called subscription_signups. There i have a New method, that helps me create a Subscription, and it executes a private method called `add_plan_to_cookies`.

**This is my controller**

```
  def new
    @subscription_signup = SubscriptionSignup.new(account_id: current_account.id)
    add_plan_to_cookies
  end

  private 
  
   def add_plan_to_cookies
    plan = current_account.base_plans.find_by(id: params[:base_plan])&.current_plan
    remember_plan(plan.id) if plan.present?
    @plan = current_account.base_plans.find_by(id: cookies.signed[:plan])&.current_plan
  end
```

```
def remember_plan(plan)
  cookies.signed[:plan] = plan
end
```

In the `add_plan_to_cookies` method, the plan is obtained through the `base_plan_id` and then another method called `remember_plan` is executed and saves the plan in a cookie. **What i have to do is using the plan that was saved in the cookie.** & I can obtain that with the second query, but there has to be a better way.

So first I get the ID of the params, look for the plan and add its id to the cookies. Then i have to use that id to search for the plan that you already got before.

**MY problem is that the im doing too queries for something that is kind of the same, and i dont now have to refactor it. anyone has a suggestion?**

In the view i have something like this.

```
<% if @plan.present? %>
  <%= @plan.name %>
  <%= image_tag @plan.base_plan.cover(:medium), class: "img-responsive "%>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you store the id of current_plan in the cookie and then you load a base_plan with the id of your current_plan and then proceeds to check if it has yet another current_plan. Written like this:

```rb
@plan = current_account.base_plans.find_by(id: current_account.base_plans.find_by(id: params[:base_plan])&.current_plan || cookies.signed[:plan])&.current_plan
```

I don't know your datastucture, but did you perhaps mean to write something like?

```rb
remember_plan(params[:base_plan]) if plan.present?
```

If that's the case I would write it like so:

```rb
def new
  @subscription_signup = SubscriptionSignup.new(account_id: current_account.id)
  @plan = load_plan
  remember_plan(@plan)
end

private

def load_plan
  plan = current_account.base_plans.find_by(id: params[:base_plan_id])&.current_plan
  plan ||= current_account.base_plans.find_by(id: cookies.signed[:plan_id])&.current_plan
end

def remember_plan(plan)
  cookies.signed[:plan_id] = plan.id if plan.present?
end
```

I don't entirely understand the intentions of your code, but as I see it you want to load the plan in to an instance variable so it is exposed to the view and also want to save the plan for later use. It's two responsibilities, and they are both in one method `add_plan_to_cookies`. I would split it up in a load and a store method.

I recommend making your variables names that contain id end with `_id`, so it's more specific what kind of object you work with. Like `params[base_plan_id]` or `cookies.signed[:plan_id]`. But it's personal preference I guess.

I might have compleetly misunderstood your code. Please let me know.